# Present Progressive and Present Simple

Tags: usage

Why can we say both  "I am studying at the University"  or "I study at the University"  but when we say " I am learning about wine"  we cannot say  "I learn about wine" ?

Comment: Actually we can and do say both "I am learning about wine" and "I learn about wine"

Comment: You can! A: "What do you do"? B: "I study at the university / learn about wine".

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. If I ask, "What do you do at the university," if you are studying oenology, you can reply, "I learn about wine." This response describes a general (albeit not infinite) state, as opposed to one occurring over a more or less fixed or set time. In the former instance, the simple present is appropriate, and in the latter, the present progressive is appropriate. (More information: https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/simpre-prepro).